# ios location related bug

Tags: ios, nsstring, location

I am seeing a weird bug that I am looking for help with.

I have an iPad iOS 7 app that allows people to fill out forms. Their entries are stored in a Sqlite database. When they reopen a form they have worked on entries they have made are redisplayed.

When the iPad goes to a new city all the entries seem to disappear. When the app is reactivated in the new location the current page appears fine, but scrolling left or right shows nothing but blank fields. The current page is also blank if you scroll away from it and back to it.

If you print or email the form while its data is not visible, the output contains all the missing data. The data also comes back if you double-press the home button, truly exit the app, and then restart it. But simply re-opening the form does not bring the data back.

When I took my Mac and iPad to a new city, the disappearing data effect happened but went away shortly after I started testing it. I don’t know whether it always goes away eventually. I didn’t test for it immediately when I got back home, and when I did start testing the bug was not happening.

Each field is backed by an object that includes a strong string property for the field’s value. The only thing I know for sure is that in forms with invisible data that string property is nil for fields that should have data. All the other field properties retain their correct values.

So far, a change in physical location is the only thing I have found that triggers this bug. My app uses location when the user gives permission, but runs fine without it. Changing the location in the simulator does not trigger the bug. I need a way to reproduce this bug but dread having to travel all over the state (or country!) just see it.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts or suggestions.

Comment: Are you sure this is due to a change in location and not, perhaps, waiting a longer period of time. If your app isn't dealing with it's internal state properly it might appear to be correct when you put it in the background then move to the foreground. If, however, you wait for a period of time (for example when travelling) and re-launch the app, perhaps a background process has run incorrectly or your app has been "killed" by iOS and is restarting incorrectly when it restarts.

Comment: I'm sure it's not just a long wait time. Most users don't travel. They can work on a form, not work on it for days or put the iPad down for days, then open the app again and pick up right where they left off. I don't run any any background processes.